# How to set a absolutePanel onTop in gwt?

Tags: gwt, z-index, css-position

I have a problem with my Internet Explorer browser.
When I set an `AbsolutePanel` over an existing `AbsolutePanel`, it is displayed  in the backgroundof the other absolutePanel.

In Firefox and Chrome these examples work perfect... but not in IE.
Whats wrong?

In this example panel 1 is in top of panel 2_1:

```
AbsolutePanel panel0= new AbsolutePanel();
AbsolutePanel panel1= new AbsolutePanel();
AbsolutePanel panel2= new AbsolutePanel();
AbsolutePanel panel2_0= new AbsolutePanel();
AbsolutePanel panel2_1= new AbsolutePanel();
 //.....adding some stuff to the panels
panel0.add(panel2,0,10);
panel0.add(panel1,100,0);
panel2.add(panel2_0,0,0);
panel2.add(panel2_1,100,0);
panel2.getElement().getStyle().setOverflow(Overflow.VISIBLE);
panel2_1.getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.ABSOLUTE);
panel2_1.getElement().getStyle().setTop(20, Unit.PX);
panel2_1.getElement().getStyle().setLeft(120, Unit.PX);
panel2_1.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(100);
```

Sure, I can add panel2 after panel1 and it works in the IE. But Panel1 have a Overflow,too

Comment: This sounds like a plain HTML/CSS question, since AbsolutePanel is a relatively simple GWT widget. Can you paste the generated HTML and CSS into a JsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)? That way, you'll get help from more than just the GWT crowd.

Comment: Also, what's with all the absolute panels? Have you considered using a dock layout panel, or something like that?